# Show percentage in Keras after predict_proba

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

So I trained a model with tensorflow and keras, which works just fine.

I load in the model and want to make a prediction, but it only prints out the category. I also want to see how sure the model was, so therefore printing out the percentage. I saw that predict_proba used to work but is now canceld for some reason. How did you solve this problem?

My code is the following:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Conv2D(
        32,(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape= X_train.shape[1:]),
    keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(
       64,(3,3),activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(
        128,(3,3),activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(
        256,(3,3),activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(
        512,(3,3),activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'), 
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    ])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()


def prepare(filepath):
    img_size = 100;
    img_array = cv2.imread(filepath)
    new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (img_size, img_size));
    return new_array.reshape(-1, img_size, img_size, 3);

Xnew = array([[0.0000]])
# make a prediction
ynew = model.predict(prepare('dog.9505.jpg'))
# show the inputs and predicted outputs
print("X=%s, Predicted=%s" % (Xnew[0], ynew[0]))
```

Comment: if your model prints only the category, you have probably used in your code an argmax function. can you please provide your model code?

Comment: I updated it in my question :) @noober

Comment: Here is the link to my GitHub Repo: https://github.com/Bastistr99/Image_Recognition

Comment: have you tried using predict_proba() instead of predict?

Comment: Yes, predict_proba is not supported any more, at least this was stated on the keras page..